# Limit to data fetched from database using dpo

Tags: php

i'm using foreach to insert data into my website, but my database happens to have too many items.. can anyone help me get only 12 items per page on my website?

```
$lista_banco = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts"); //seleciona a tabela filmes
$lista_banco->execute(); //executa o comando
$filmes = $lista_banco->fetchAll();
```

in this array i need some informations like title, genre, etc..

my foreach

```
<?php foreach ($filmes as $filme)?>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card__cover">
                        <img src="<?php echo $filme["capa"]?>" alt="">
                        <a href="#" class="card__play">
                            <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__content">
                        <h3 class="card__title"><a href="#"><?php echo $filme["titulo"]?></a></h3>
                        <span class="card__category">
                            <a href="#"><?php echo $filme["genero"]?></a>
                        </span>
                        <span class="card__rate"><i class="icon ion-ios-star"></i><?php echo $filme["nota"]?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
```

is there a way to put a limit per page like 12?

Comment: You mean like `SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 12`?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `LIMIT` to the SQL query to get a maximum qty of items:

```
$lista_banco = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 12"); //seleciona a tabela filmes
$lista_banco->execute(); //executa o comando
$filmes = $lista_banco->fetchAll();
```

It's better to have in a variable and maybe you want to add a pagination using OFFSET, so it looks like this:

```
$limit = 12;
$offset = $page * $limit;
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT %s OFFSET %s", $limit, $offset);
$lista_banco = $pdo->prepare($sql); //seleciona a tabela filmes
$lista_banco->execute(); //executa o comando
$filmes = $lista_banco->fetchAll();
```